# Array Count +1 , site doesn't load

Tags: php, arrays, count

I've defined it

```
$array = array(
"0" => "2",
"1" => "4",
"2" => "6",
"3" => "8",
"4" => "10",
"5" => "12",
"6" => "14",
"7" => "16",
"8" => "18",
"9" => "20",
"10" => "22",
"11" => "24",
"12" => "26",
"13" => "28",
"14" => "30",
"15" => "32"
);
```

then it should count all numbers from 0 to 16

```
for($i=0; $i <= 16; $i++){
```

and I use it with $i for the number and $array[$i] for the defined value
but it doesn't load, where is my error?
btw before that I've tried to question it all like
`if 0 == .....` and it worked till 10 times repeated then it stopped showing the page.

Comment: are you sure it is not loading value for `$array[$i]`?

Comment: it doesnt shows anything when i put it in, not even an error if enabled and the rest of the page is white too, not infecting only that parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$i <= 16;` to `$i < 16;`.

Your for loop is going past the end of the array you have defined.

```
for($i=0; $i < 16; $i++){
    echo $array[$i] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: thanks that works but how can i show only the result that is defined in db? when i go for if(row["value"] == $i) { i get showed all 16

Comment: There is nothing database related in your question that I can see. If the value of `row['value']` is an integer then comparing it to `$i` before the echo in my example should work.

Comment: ah nevermind i put it right above each instead of taking all the code inside one of it , thanks a lot